# Grayscale to tri-color conversion

Tags: python

I would like to change the output PNG of [this script](https://github.com/akapila011/Text-to-Image/blob/master/text_to_image/encode.py) to tri-color (red, blue, yellow)

Instead of its current grayscale format.

I figure I need to change lines 34-45, but im not sure how to go about it.

```
img = Image.new("L", size)  # grayscale, blank black image

ind = 0

for row in range(0, size[0]):

    for col in range(0, size[1]):

        if ind < text_length:  # only change pixel value for length of text

            pixel_value = convert_char_to_int(text[ind], limit=limit)

            img.putpixel((row, col), pixel_value)

            ind += 1

        else:  # end of text, leave remaining pixel(s) black to indicate null

            break

img.save(result_path)

return result_path
```

Any advice would be useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PIL documentation for `Image.putpixel()`](http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.putpixel):

> im.putpixel(xy, colour)
>
> Modifies the pixel at the given position. The colour is given as a single numerical value for single-band images, and a tuple for multi-band images.

So, to insert a coloured pixel using RGB format:

```
img = Image.new("RBG", size)  # RGB image

img.putpixel((row, col), (r,g,b))
```

You may also be interested in [`Image.convert()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.convert)

Comment: Thanks! I've been told I also need to change `convert_char_to_int` to return a tuple when encoding, and converting that tuple back into a character when decoding. How do I do this?

Comment: I can't answer that as I don't have enough information about what you're trying to do, what format `text` is, and what your intended input looks like. Perhaps read 3 characters at a time to create an RGB tuple?

Comment: That's what was suggest to me elsewhere as well....would it be possible for you to explain how one does that exactly? I'd like to do something like this: https://github.com/colorsafe/colorsafe/blob/master/images/sector_c2.png  Where its just 3 colors...not sure how its done

Comment: I now have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334528/10073689 but this is just RGB and not strictly 3 colours...need help with that part