# Convert character(s) to tuple and back

Tags: python, base64, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am trying to change the output of this encoder:
https://github.com/akapila011/Text-to-Image/blob/master/text_to_image/encode.py
from grayscale to a tri-color scheme such as the one shown here: [Tricolor](https://github.com/colorsafe/colorsafe/blob/master/images/sector_c2.png)
The main lines of code I need to change from the encoder are:

```
img = Image.new("L", size)  # grayscale, blank black image

ind = 0

for row in range(0, size[0]):

    for col in range(0, size[1]):

        if ind < text_length:  # only change pixel value for length of text

            pixel_value = convert_char_to_int(text[ind], limit=limit)

            img.putpixel((row, col), pixel_value)

            ind += 1

        else:  # end of text, leave remaining pixel(s) black to indicate null

            break

img.save(result_path)

return result_path
```

Im loading in base64 text only, so im working with 64 characters strictly.
I was told that I needed to change `convert_char_to_int` to return the tuple as an RGB value. But im not sure how to do this? Do I convert int to rgb, if so, how so?
I'd need to reverse the process in order for me to [Decode](https://github.com/akapila011/Text-to-Image/blob/master/text_to_image/encode.py) it back into text too.

Comment: The Encoder link is dead

Comment: since rgb is not a standard python type, it is crucial to know what library you are using for Image processing in order to give a good answer.

Comment: Weird, I don't know why it didn't link there. Edited. I was thinking just the RGB mode? http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: I added the PIL tag, as that is what this question is really about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is the library that they are using.  To answer your question, it really depends on how you want to encode your rgb values as chars.  One way to do it would be to let one char represent the brightness of one of the colors - so it would take three chars to represent a pixel.  The other point be sure of is that your chars will only represent values between 0 and 63 instead of the usual 0 to 255.  Therefore you will want to multiply each value by 4 so that the image is not extremely dark.

Here's how I would rewrite the `encode` function:

```
img = Image.new("RGB", size)  # RGB image

ind = 0

for row in range(0, size[0]):

    for col in range(0, size[1]):

        if ind <= text_length - 3:  # only change pixel value for length of text

            r = convert_char_to_int(text[ind], limit=64) * 4
            g = convert_char_to_int(text[ind+1], limit=64) * 4
            b = convert_char_to_int(text[ind+2], limit=64) * 4

            img.putpixel((row, col), (r, g, b))

            ind += 3

        else:  # end of text, leave remaining pixel(s) black to indicate null

            break

img.save(result_path)

return result_path
```

Comment: OP is encoding `base64` text, I don't think he's concerned with picture beauty =)

Comment: Dude youre the best! That's what I was trying to do to, to get 3 characters to represent a pixel. Im getting a "index error: image index out of range" though right now

Comment: @lenik Well, not picture beauty, but I wouldn't mind it to be as clear as possible like the tricolor pic from the top

Comment: Ah I think I had the ranges in the for loops wrong... one sec

Comment: @lenik you are right, I'll fix that.  As to your comment on picture beauty, if one does not multiply the 8-bit values by 4, the brightest color will be [0x3F3F3F](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/3F3F3F)!

Comment: @BenJones it's called steganography, encoding messages in the image, nobody cares about the brightness as long as the message can be decoded back =)

Comment: That's the other part to this, the decoding using the decode.py...at the moment @BenJones it works, but im still getting a grayscale output

Comment: Hmm... did you change the [mode](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) in `Image.new(mode, color)` from `"L"` to `"RGB"`?

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong, but it works now...looks like: https://imgur.com/a/hJOwiJ0  (black included?)..but is it possible to channel it to only 3 colours? Not just RGB?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Which three colors did you want, and how did you want that mapped to your 8-bit encoding?

Comment: Maybe red, blue, yellow? I was going off the idea that is shown from: https://github.com/colorsafe/colorsafe/blob/master/images/sector_c2.png  Im not sure, that's what ive been trying to figure out...how to get it to only 3 colours and then reverse the process so that I can decode it back into base64 text

Comment: It looks like there are 4 colors in that encoding: magenta, yellow, blue and white.  This means that the most compact encoding would be to have each char represent 8 pixels, although this is quite different from what I have written above, and I am not inclined to rewrite the whole thing.  However the inner part of the matrix would be like:

    `if text[ind] % 4 == 0: putpixel((row, col), 0xFF00FF) # magenta`

Comment: Super helpful. So each character = 8 pixels, got it. Its a lot more complex than I had anticipated !

Comment: You don't have to make it that complicated! I'm just saying that is the theoretical maximum for efficiency.  In practice, you may want to make it more like 1 = magenta, 2 = cyan, 3 = yellow, and 4 = white.  Before continuing on however, I would suggest you read up on [Color Depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) and also read through some of the docs for PIL.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember reading this wiki a bit back....so 2 bit has 4 colors apparently, so I guess that would be perfect? Id like to be able to just adjust your code to do so...I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to encode different characters into different colour channels:

```
for row in range(0, size[0]):
    for col in range(0, size[1]):

        if ind >= text_length : break # only change pixel value for length of text

        r = convert_char_to_int(text[ind], limit=limit)
        ind = max( ind+1, text_length - 1)  # don't go beyond text length
        g = convert_char_to_int(text[ind], limit=limit)
        ind = max( ind+1, text_length - 1)
        b = convert_char_to_int(text[ind], limit=limit)
        ind += 1

        img.putpixel((row, col), (r,g,b))
```

Comment: Thanks :) I am trying your method as well.